# List<Hashmap<String,String> data setting in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to add the following String datas in the textview. As I am new learner so I can't understand how add those. Please help me. I want to add nameOfplace,address,rating in the textview. DisplayNearByplaces()
method is connected to the onPostExecute() method.

```
    public class PlaceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    List<String> data;
    Context context;

    public PlaceAdapter(List<String> data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.details_row, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void DisplayNearByPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearByPlacesList) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nearByPlacesList.size(); i++) {

            HashMap<String, String> googleNearByPlaces = nearByPlacesList.get(i);
            String nameOfPlace = googleNearByPlaces.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googleNearByPlaces.get("vicinity");
            String reference = googleNearByPlaces.get("reference");
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(googleNearByPlaces.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googleNearByPlaces.get("lng"));
            String address = googleNearByPlaces.get("formatted_address");
            String rating = googleNearByPlaces.get("rating");


        }


    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView t1, t2, t3, t4;
        Button sel;
        ImageButton gmap;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            t1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_name);
            t2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            t3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            t4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);

            sel = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sel_place);
            gmap = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.map_place);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to go through the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_397052992298-ADGP_Hybrid+%7C+AW+SEM+%7C+BKWS+~+Places+%7C+BMM+%7C+Google+Maps+Places+API-KWID_43700049595992091-kwd-18857163995-userloc_1005390&utm_term=KW_%2Bgoogle%20%2Bplaces-ST_%2Bgoogle+%2Bplaces&gclid=CjwKCAjwpqv0BRABEiwA-TySwVwRbXmZ3pgs2xNt_McmHIaJ0WUrDw1VJqKkd1FQ3JkjB1qCQAelqBoCodQQAvD_BwE)

Comment: I have already added marker on the nearest places. But now I want to make their list using recyclerview

Comment: set text and details in ` @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }` method

Comment: I know , I have to work with @Override public void onBindViewHolder@NonNull. But I am unable to add the values, I tried it